# RequestMapping with multiple endpoints and LazyInitializationException exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I already have seen different answers for the LazyInitializationException (could not initialize proxy - no Session) exception but I think my problem is different.

I have a working API and a security-context.xml with <s:intercept-url> for each endpoints and I want to create a second API with different privileges.

Then, I have added a second endpoint to my already existing controller :

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping(path =["/settings/", "/v2/settings/"])
class ThisIsAController {
```

And I have added the endpoints to my security-context.xml

```
<s:intercept-url pattern="/settings/create/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE')" />
<s:intercept-url pattern="/v2/settings/create/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE')" />
```

But When I tried to reach :

> /v2/settings/....

I have the following exception :

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.model.ModelClass.entries, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

And when I tried to reach the first api it works well.

Does anyone have any idea where the exception could be coming from?

Thanks

Comment: Does your controller execute the same code for both of your endpoints?

Comment: @Lewis_McReu, yes it does.